# objectify count all entities in datastore

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, objectify

I am using objectify v6. I want to get a count of all entities in my datastore. It looks like there is a limit on look up operation in datastore https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/limits.

In my datastore, I have 2000 entities, when I do

```
ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(MyEntity.class).keys();
```

this works, gives no error, but when I do

```
ObjectifyService.ofy().load().type(MyEntity.class).list()
```

this gives me error saying there is a limit on query, does that mean I can get a count of all entities by counting all the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can count all the entities in your kind by using `keys()`... right up until you run into the same problem, which is that your query takes too long. I don't know how far you can get but I doubt you'll reach millions. This approach will probably only perform reasonably for thousands.

There isn't a good equivalent of `SELECT COUNT(*)` in the datastore. You can track adds and removes in a sharded counter if you need an up-to-date answer. If you only need an approximate, you can use map/reduce (see the `__scatter__` property) or you can just look at the statistics that Google periodically recomputes:

https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/concepts/stats